# Coding a responsive site that centers itself on any browser

Tags: responsive-design, responsive

I apologize if this question is super simple. I have been trying to use a third party website builder for a client for ease of access/editing later on but he really wants a responsive site that resizes and centers itself no matter what browser/resolution it's displayed on. I am pretty sure I will need to just start from scratch and build him something completely customized. I'm struggling to even know where to start with this as coding responsive sites is still new to me. Any help or guides that someone could point me to would be greatly appreciated.

```
#page {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:960px;
}

#stage {
margin: 1em auto;
width: 360px;
height: 540px;
}

#stage a {
position: absolute;
}
#stage a img {
padding: 0px;
border: 0px solid #ccc;
background: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the body to be always centered so it doesn't have layout problems on different devices or do you want every element to be center aligned?
I think it's the first one.
You could use `width:95vw;` on the body element and `margin:auto;`.
You could work with media queries.
It's also important to add the viewport meta tag in the head.
Let me know if I understood the question

Comment: I want it to be responsive. I am going to post the code and maybe someone can give me feedback on what is going on. I want the site to be middle centered no matter the resolution of the screen.